# Available Colors for SetConsoleTextAttribute

Tags: api, delphi, winapi

im working with SetConsoleTextAttribute API (Delphi to be specific), well anyway i cannot find a list of available colors anywhere?? can anyone help me out

Comment: See [`WIN32SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32SetConsoleTextAttribute.htm) for a list of colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes).  Colors are formed by ORing different constants.  For instance:

> An application can combine the foreground and background constants to
>   achieve different colors. For example, the following combination
>   results in bright cyan text on a blue background.
>
> FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY |
>   BACKGROUND_BLUE

For more Turbo/Borland Pascal CRTish implementations of such, see [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=7109).  The colors available in the Windows console via SetConsoleTextAttribute work out roughly to be the same ones as the CRT unit, so any more relevant details can be found there.

Comment: Thanks alot! , you were a huge help! your time is also appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

There a 4 Bits used for the foreground color

```
  FOREGROUND_BLUE;  //1
  FOREGROUND_GREEN; //2
  FOREGROUND_RED;   //4
  FOREGROUND_INTENSITY; //8
```

which will give 16 possible colors. (0-15)

The next 4 bits are used for background color with the same scheme

Comment: Thank you so much, What a great help! I truly appreciate your time